# react native ui not loaded properly during VOIP call

Tags: react-native, apple-push-notifications, voip, callkit, pushkit

so i'm currently work on app that implement callback voip call on ios, we use `RNCallKeep` and `RNVoipPushNotification` to make it happen. we manage to handle for all state including when app in foreground and background but the thing is when app is on killed state and voip call came in to device after i tapped answer or reject app manage to open but the UI became very weird kinda unstyle when on home screen like below
[image: evidence]

here the code;

```
AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
--------

[RNCallKeep setup:@{
    @"appName": @"appname",
    @"imageName": @"applogo.png",
    @"maximumCallGroups": @1,
    @"maximumCallsPerCallGroup": @1,
    @"supportsVideo": @YES,
  }];
--------

}
```

and on js side

```
App.js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

            RNCallKeep.addEventListener('answerCall', ({ callUUID }) => {
                // action here
            });

            RNCallKeep.addEventListener('endCall', ({ callUUID }) => {
                // action here
            });

            RNCallKeep.addEventListener('didLoadWithEvents', this.onDidLoadWithNativeEvents);
    }
}
```

can someone please help me what did i do wrong? i've read much about this but still cannot manage to solve this for few days now. Thanks

Comment: Hi, 
I'm facing the same issue on RN 0.61.3. 
did you find any solution to this?

Comment: hi, our solution was replace Dimensions.get('window') into Dimensions.get('screen')

Comment: i'm not sure if the solution was directly related to voip or the js thing